# JQuery & PHP: How to pass appended button value to jquery? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am appending items (articles) to a content with some originally existing articles, each article has a button for its deleting, editing, opening. I use jquery & ajax. 
I want these appended articles' buttons to be able to pass each of their values to jquery click function, as well as produce all the logic there (same way as original articles' buttons do). 
Is it possible to do something that way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Infinite Software Blog</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/blog/jquery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.del_btn').click(function () {
                var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
                var ajaxurl = '/blog/helpers/delete_post.php',
                    data = {'action': clickBtnValue};
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function () {
                    alert("Post was successfully deleted");
                });
            });
            $('.edit_btn').click(function () {
                var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
                console.log(clickBtnValue);
                var ajaxurl = '/blog/edit_post.php',
                    data = {'action': clickBtnValue};
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function () {
                    window.location.assign("/blog/helpers/updatePost.php");
                });
            });
            $('.post_content_btn').click(function () {
                var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
                var ajaxurl = '/blog/view/post.php',
                    data = {'action': clickBtnValue};
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function () {
                    window.location.assign("/blog/post.php");
                });
            });
            $('.more_posts_btn').click(function () {
                var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
                var ajaxurl = '/blog/helpers/show_more_posts.php',
                    data = {'action': clickBtnValue};
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (output) {
                    $(".content").append(output);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/blog/styles/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

show_more_post.php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/blog/model/classes.php");
    $post = new posts();
    $postsToDisplay = $post->getPostsQty($_POST['action']);
    $newRecordsIndex = $_POST['action'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $postsToDisplay; $i++) {
        $record = $post->getPost($newRecordsIndex);
        $newRecordsIndex++;
        $elementToAdd = '<article class="topContent"><header><h2><a href="#" title="' . $record[1] . '">' .
            $record[1] . '</a></h2></header><footer><p class="post-author">Author: ' . $record[2] . '</p>' .
            '</footer><content>' . $record[6] . '</content><footer><p class="post-date">Publish date: ' .
            $record[3] . '</p>' . '<p class="post-time">Publish time: ' . $record[4] . '</p><form><button type="submit" 
            title="Delete post"' . ' value="' . $record[0] . '" class="del_btn">Delete post</button><button type="submit" 
            title="Edit post"' . ' value="' . $record[0] . '" class="edit_btn">Edit post</button><button type="submit" 
            title="Open post in a new tab" value="' . $record[0] . '" class="post_content_btn">Open Post</button>
            </form></footer></article>';
        echo($elementToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(document).on('<event>', '<selector>', function() {});` to make available events on dom elements, that creates after script init.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Did not get it at first, but change click to on and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to go in a simple way, You can use live table update strategy where you can simply update the data directly from the UI and delete or add as well. Find the below code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function load(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'db.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success:function(data){
            $("#load").html(data);
        }
    });

    };
    load();
    $(document).on('click', '.bton', function(){
        var name= $(this).data("id");
        if(confirm("Do you want to delete this row"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{id:name},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    load();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','#add', function(){
        var addName= $("#name").text();
        var addComp= $("#company").text();
        $.ajax({
            url:'insert.php',
            method:'POST',
            data: {name:addName, company:addComp},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                load();
            }
        });
    });


    $(document).on('blur','.type', function(){
        var editID=$(this).data('id1');
        var editName= $(this).text();
        alert(editName);    
    })
   });
```

for reference click [here](https://github.com/WeDevelopOnline/liveTableUpdate), download file and use to understand better.

Comment: My pleasure. :)